# How to add style to a parent div only if it's child div content is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add CSS style using Jquery, to a parent `div` only if the parent's child `div` content is empty?

Example:

```
 <div class="parentDivClass">
    <div class="theContent">          
        <div class="subContent"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="parentDivClass">
    <div class="theContent">          
        <div class="subContent">some text</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="parentDivClass">
    <div class="theContent">          
        <div class="subContent"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So if there is no text inside a `subContent` class, then I want to add `padding-bottom: 20px` to `parentDivClass`.  If there is text inside `subContent`, then no CSS to be added on `parentDivClass`.

I approached it like this but for some reason it is not adding style to `parentDivClass` if `subContent` has no text:

```
if( $('.subContent').is(':empty') )
{
    $('.parentDivClass').css({'padding-bottom': '20px'});
}
```

Is my logic going wrong some where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` condition is true if any `.subContent` div is empty. And the `.css()` call doesn't only apply to the parent of the empty div, it's done on all `.parentDivClass` elements.

You need to relate the empty `.subContent` div to its containing `.parentDivClass`.

```js
$(".subContent:empty").closest(".parentDivClass").css({'padding-bottom': '20px'});
```

```css
.parentDivClass {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentDivClass">
    <div class="theContent">          
        <div class="subContent"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="parentDivClass">
    <div class="theContent">          
        <div class="subContent">not empty</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="parentDivClass">
    <div class="theContent">          
        <div class="subContent"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use JS if a thing is achievable with CSS.

There's `:has` css selector, check the browser compatibility though:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#browser_compatibility

```css
.parentDivClass {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: solid black 1px;
}

.parentDivClass:has(.subContent:empty){
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentDivClass">
    <div class="theContent">          
        <div class="subContent"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="parentDivClass">
    <div class="theContent">          
        <div class="subContent">not empty</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="parentDivClass">
    <div class="theContent">          
        <div class="subContent"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But you can do that more simple - use `min-height`:

```css
.parentDivClass {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: solid black 1px;
}

.parentDivClass{
  min-height : 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentDivClass">
    <div class="theContent">          
        <div class="subContent"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="parentDivClass">
    <div class="theContent">          
        <div class="subContent">not empty</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="parentDivClass">
    <div class="theContent">          
        <div class="subContent"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for showing a CSS approach, this makes sense.